# Rails 5 - created_at and updated_at classes

Tags: oracle, types, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm experiencing different behaviour between Rails 4 and 5; specifically, the class of `created_at` and `updated_at` values of a model in code.  In Rails 4, it shows that they are `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, but Rails 5 just has them as a `Date`.  The values also (obviously) print out differently with `puts`.

I have not changed the database type of these values.  I'm using Oracle with the **activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter** gem (v1.7.0), and the columns were created "normally" in migrations with `t.timestamps` with no special configuration.

```
» bundle exec rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 69059
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
[1] (pry) main: 0> Rails.version
=> "4.2.7.1"
[2] (pry) main: 0> Document.first.created_at.class
[ SQL Omitted ]
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone　←←←←←←←←←←←← HERE
[3] (pry) main: 0> puts Document.first.updated_at
[ SQL Omitted ]
2016-09-08 17:05:18 -0600　←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←← HERE
=> nil
[4] (pry) main: 0> !!!

» git flow feature checkout rails-5
Switched to branch 'feature/rails-5'

» bundle exec rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 69533
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
[1] (pry) main: 0> Rails.version
=> "5.0.1"
[2] (pry) main: 0> Document.first.created_at.class
[ SQL Omitted ]
=> Date　←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←← HERE
[3] (pry) main: 0> puts Document.first.updated_at
[ SQL Omitted ]
2016-09-08 ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←← HERE
=> nil
```

Did they really change this, or am I doing something wrong?  What am I missing?

Comment: What database are you using and what does it say about the data type of the created_at column?

Comment: @Maltiriel:  Updated question with db info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed this in the the [activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced) documentation, but there are explicit [Rails 4.2 to 5 upgrade instructions](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/README.md#upgrade-rails-42-or-older-version-to-rails-5) that I needed to apply.

Comment: I too failed to read the documentation before finding your question. Thanks!